# lon lat are null @onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps

When I call lon,lat from server using Retrofit, Data are here;

Double lon,lat;

```
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getResDetail(id, new Callback<Restaurant>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Restaurant restaurant, Response response) {

                    lon = restaurant.getLon(); // Double
                    lat = restaurant.getLat(); // Double
                    Log.i("lon_", String.valueOf(restaurant.getLon())); //    lon_: -128.861048
                    Log.i("lat_", String.valueOf(restaurant.getLat())); //    lat_: 51.09783    
            }
```

But @onMapReady lon,lat are null. Why?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    Log.i("lonn_", String.valueOf(lon)); // null
    Log.i("latt_", String.valueOf(lat)); // null
    map = googleMap;
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lon);

}
```

Comment: i think your getting lat lon after onMapReady has been called

Comment: @Nikhil Sharma I call  `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` after NetworkEngine

Comment: call it on `public void success()` method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onMapReady()` is called before your Retrofit's API call.

So initialize your `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` inside your Retrofit's API call's `success()` method.

Answer (score 1):

> @onMapReady lon,lat are null. Why?

because lon and lat has no value here means both are null. I think you are opening the map before the network call. You should do it like this-

```
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getResDetail(id, new Callback<Restaurant>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Restaurant restaurant, Response response) {

            lon = restaurant.getLon(); // Double
            lat = restaurant.getLat(); // Double
            Log.i("lon_", String.valueOf(restaurant.getLon())); //    lon_: -128.861048
            Log.i("lat_", String.valueOf(restaurant.getLat())); //    lat_: 51.09783    
            openMap();// it's just a method name you can change it with user suitable method name.
    }
}
```

do all the map related things inside **openMap()** method.

```
private void openMap(){
    // do your stuff here..

   // something like to call another method to open map for you or,
  // write all the code here to open a map like this--
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

It is just an idea, hope it will helpful.